# Displays/hide iframe on button click

Tags: angular

I have an established app that I want to fork.
I added .html, .component.ts, .module.ts as below.
I think that my problem is simple, but I don't know how to code in Angular.
I want to add a button that allows me to hide/how my iframes (button 1 : iframe 1 / button 2 : iframe 2).
I only added one button. the button is displayed but when I click it I can see nothing.
Could you please help me with this matter?

### .module.ts :

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
    import { AppComponent } from './App.component';
    @NgModule({
        declarations: [
            AppComponent,
        ],
        imports:[],
        providers: [],
        entryComponents: [
           AppComponent
           ]
        })
    export class AppModule { }
```

### .component.ts:

```
import { 
        Component,
        OnInit } from '@angular/core';
    @Component({
         selector: 'mui-App',
        templateUrl: 'App.component.html'
    })  
    export class AppComponent implements OnInit{ 
    public ngOnInit() {
        var x = document.getElementById("f1");
        if (x.style.display === "none") {
            x.style.display = "block";
       } else {
            x.style.display = "none";
        }
    }    
    }
```

### .html

```
<button onclick="ngOnInit()">Show</button>
    <div id="f1">
        <iframe src="http://myiframe" WIDTH = 1850 HEIGHT= 970 >
        </iframe>
    </div>

    <div id="f2">
         <iframe src="http://myiframe2" WIDTH = 1850 HEIGHT= 970 >
         </iframe>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this in your code...

In HTML

```
<button (click)="showMe =! showMe">Show</button>
<div *ngIf="showMe">
    <iframe src="http://myiframe" WIDTH = '1850' HEIGHT= '970' >
    </iframe>
</div>

<div *ngIf="!showMe">
     <iframe src="http://myiframe2" WIDTH = '1850' HEIGHT= '970' >
     </iframe>
</div>
```

In Typescript

```
public showMe = false;
```

Comment: Thank you !
But if I have 4 iframes and I want to add 4 buttons, each one displays an iframe ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

In your template.

```
    <button (click)="hideElement()">Show</button>
    <div #f1>
        <iframe src="http://myiframe" WIDTH = 1850 HEIGHT= 970 >
        </iframe>
    </div>

    <div #f2>
         <iframe src="http://myiframe2" WIDTH = 1850 HEIGHT= 970 >
         </iframe>
    </div>
```

In your component.

```
 import { Component, OnInit, AfterViewInit, ViewChild, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'mui-App',
  templateUrl: 'App.component.html'
})

export class AppComponent implements AfterViewInit {

  @ViewChild('f1') f1: ElementRef;
  @ViewChild('f2') f2: ElementRef;

  public ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.hideElement()
  }

  public hideElement(): void {
    if (this.f1.nativeElement.style.display === "none") {
      this.f1.nativeElement.style.display = "block";
    } else {
      this.f1.nativeElement.style.display = "none";
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply,
I copied your code but that doesn't work. I ignore where is the problem !

Comment: Did you get any erros? Try to put a `deugger` inside the `hideElement()` and debug the code

Comment: I am getting that :
TypeError: Cannot read property 'nativeElement' of undefined

Comment: I find this in the application I wanna fork :
export declare class ElementRef<T = any> {

    nativeElement: T;
    constructor(nativeElement: T);
}

Comment: Now check.. I updated the answer. I was using `onclick` instead of `(click)` in html button

Comment: Look at this [stackbliz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/app-iframe). It works without any errors. See the app.component.html and app.component.ts

Comment: Can't I do it with ngIf ?